# Parameter Passing with Azure Get Service

Tags: azure, xamarin.forms, azure-mobile-services

I am not sure how to do this, new with azure, i am using "public interface IMobileServiceSyncTable : IMobileServiceSyncTable" of Azure and to fetch the records from one particular table, i am using below in a method:
"query = table.CreateQuery();
await table.PullAsync(typeof(T).Name, query);"

this gets me all the records of this particular table, now i wish to pass a parameter viz USERID, so i get only those records that belongs to this user.

Can anyone help me with an example for this?

Also it would be great if there is an example to fetch data with multiple parameters.

Thanks in Advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just add a `Where` clause to the query, as in regular LINQ:

```
await todoTable.PullAsync("todoItems" + userid, syncTable.Where(u => u.UserId == userid));
```

Also, if you are using multiple queries against the same table name, make sure you use a unique query name (the first parameter) for them. This is because incremental sync uses this query name in order to store the last updated value for the previous sync operation.

For more information, see [Offline Data Sync in Azure Mobile Apps](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-us/documentation/articles/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync/).

Finally, it's usually not a good idea to do user ID filtering on the client, because it is less secure. Anyone could issue an HTTP call to retrieve values that do not belong to them. A better way is to adjust the query on the server.

For examples of this, see:

- For a Node.js backend: [30 Days of Zumo.v2 (Azure Mobile Apps): Day 6 – Personal Tables](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/11/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-6-personal-tables/)
- For .NET: [Sample of Where clause in TableController](https://github.com/azure-appservice-samples/ContosoMoments/blob/master/src/Cloud/ContosoMoments.API/Controllers/TableControllers/AlbumController.cs#L40).

Comment: Thanks a ton, the where clause thing was really helpful, had few other doubts with regards to offline data sync, the azure request needs a query id, what is a query id?

Also, if that the last record inserted ID, than what happen to the data that has been received and is now updated. how does azure track the update changes?? any example on suing the offline data sync?

Comment: Please read the article on Offline Data Sync that I linked above, it explains all of that. If my answer was helpful, please accept it. :)