# how to Pull data with paramter using Azure Offline Sync?

Tags: azure-mobile-services

I have schema as below and I would like to know if I can get all the TaskCategoryMappings by CategoryId when I have to pulll all data. I went through the documentation [here](https://adrianhall.github.io/develop-mobile-apps-with-csharp-and-azure/chapter3/relationships/) but I cant figure out how to do it ? All the examples are like [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/app-service-mobile/app-service-mobile-offline-data-sync) one based on UserId. but userid is used for also authentication and on the server side I already handle it fine to return only  mappings belong to relevant user and i want in adition to filter by CategoryId?

another SO sample is here also using userId  [Parameter Passing with Azure Get Service](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/38367610/parameter-passing-with-azure-get-service)

```
public class TaskCategoryMapping : TableData
    {
        public string TaskId { get; set; }

        public string CategoryId { get; set; }

        public string UserId { get; set; }

    }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

According to your description, I checked this issue on my side and found that it could work as expected, you could follow the details below to check your code:

**Backend models:**

```
public class Tag : EntityData
{
    public string TagName { get; set; }
    public bool Status { get; set; }
}

public class Message : EntityData
{
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public virtual Tag Tag { get; set; }
    [ForeignKey("Tag")]
    public string Tag_Id { get; set; }
}
```

**GetAllMessage action:**

```
// GET tables/Message
public IQueryable<Message> GetAllMessage()
{
    return Query();
}
```

For the client, I just invoke the online table for retrieving the message entities as follows:

**Model on client-side:**

```
public class Message
{
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public string UserId { get; set; }
    public string Text { get; set; }
    public string Tag_Id { get; set; }
}

var result=await mobileServiceClient.GetTable<Message>().Where(msg => msg.Tag_Id == "c3cd4cf8-7af0-4267-817e-f84c6f0e1733").ToListAsync();
```

For offline table, the pull operation query would

```
await messageSyncTable.PullAsync($"messages_{userid}", messageSyncTable.Where(m => m.Tag_Id == "<Tag_Id>"));
```

Use fiddler, you could find that the request would look like this:

```
https://{your-app-name}.azurewebsites.net/tables/Message?$filter=Tag_Id eq 'c3cd4cf8-7af0-4267-817e-f84c6f0e1733'
```

[image]